# Read access violation while deleting multiple nodes from a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I need to implement a doubly linked list in c++ for a small animation running on console. The linkedlist stores clouds and then they move through the console and as each cloud hits the end of screen, it needs to be deleted from linked list. As the cloud hits the end, it has a variable called alive which is set to false so it can be deleted.

I can't upload the full game code, but I have recreated the problem in dummy code by creating sample clouds where some of them have `alive = true` and `alive = false`. I have also updated the previous and next nodes of the cloud to be deleted but I still get an error:

`Exception thrown: read access violation. temp was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

Code below (include statements removed for simplicity)

**Test.cpp**

```
int main() {

    Cloud* a = new Cloud('a');
    a->alive = false;
    Node* a1 = new Node(a);
    Cloud* b = new Cloud('b');
    b->alive = false;
    Node* b1 = new Node(b);

    LinkedList list;
    list.Insert(a);
    list.Insert(b);

    Node* temp = list.head;
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data->alive == false) list.Delete(temp); // throws exception after deleting a single node.
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**LinkedList.cpp delete function**

```
void LinkedList::Delete(Node* del) {

    if (del == head) {
        OutputDebugStringA("Cloud in head");
        Node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = nullptr;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != tail->next) {

            if (temp == del) {
                if (temp->next != nullptr) {
                    OutputDebugStringA("Cloud in mid");
                    temp->prev->next = temp->next;
                    temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    OutputDebugStringA("cloud at tail");
                    tail = temp->prev;
                    tail->next = nullptr;
                    break;  
                }
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        delete temp;
        temp = nullptr;
    }
}
```

**Node.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Node::Node() {
    this->data = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(Cloud* data) {
    this->data = data;
}
```

Someone please point out where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Really need to see the `LinkedList::Insert` method as well.

Comment: Deleting from a doubly linked list should be O(1).  Yours is O(n).  Rather than debugging the crash, rethink your algorithm from first principles.

Comment: *I need to implement a doubly linked list in c++* -- Is your goal to implement a game, or implement a doubly linked list?  If it's the former, why aren't you using [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and skip all of this that you're doing now?  And even if it's to implement a doubly-linked list, you can still use `std::list` to confirm that your game logic actually works.

Comment: `Cloud* a = new Cloud('a');` -- This could simply be: `Cloud a('a');` -- There is no need to use `new` here.  If you ran your program under a memory monitor like `valgrind`, it would shout at you at the memory leaks your program it's producing.  Your overall code looks like you are using another language (Python, Java, etc.) as a model in writing C++ code.  If you do that, you will have 1) buggy programs, 2) inefficient programs, and 3) programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: *Code below (include statements removed for simplicity)* -- Do not do this.  The `#include` headers are very important when producing a [mcve].  When you do this, that means that we have to write code that is missing, thus possibly not being able to duplicate your issue. -- *but I have recreated the problem in dummy code* -- Dummy code means that you could have written a very simple, *complete* example, instead of one that is still cut out of a bigger program.

Comment: @JohnZwinck thank you for pointing it out, I didn't think of it while doing this :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I just started C++ after java hence the errors. I want to implement the list instead of using std::list since I want to implement this as a part of my learning and understanding data structures as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Zwinck and @Sam Varshavchik pointed out that the implementation of delete method was flawed and `temp` became useless after the `Delete` function returned.

I fixed it by using another temp pointer and fixing the delete method to be O(1).

**Delete Method**

```
void LinkedList::Delete(Node* del) {
    if (del == head) {
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = nullptr;
    }
    else if (del == tail) {
        tail = del->prev;
        tail->next = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        del->prev->next = del->next;
        del->next->prev = del->prev;
    }
    delete del;
}
```

**Node deletion**

```
Node* temp = cloud_list.head;
        Node* next;
        while (temp != nullptr) {
            next = temp->next;
            if (temp->data->alive == false) {
                cloud_list.Delete(temp);
            }
            temp = next;
        }
```

The deletion now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
        if (temp->data->alive == false) list.Delete(temp); // throws exception after deleting a single node.
        temp = temp->next;
```

Here, `temp` gets passed into the `Delete()` method. Afterwards `temp` gets set to `temp->next`.

In `Delete()`:

```
        delete temp;
        temp = nullptr;
```

The object referenced by the passed-in `temp` pointer (here, this `temp`, by the virtue of the preceding logic, is the same pointer that gets passed in) gets `delete`d.

After returning, `temp->next` references a deleted object.

This is at least one confirmed instance of undefined behavior in the shown code. This may or may not be the only bug.

As it's been pointed out to you in comments, this overall `Delete()` logic is fundamentally flawed. It should not involve any kind of iteration, for a doubly-linked list. You will end up fixing this bug while rewriting `Delete()` from scratch (which includes rethinking how `Delete()` itself gets called, because after it returns `temp` is no longer usable for anything).

Comment: Thanks, I will try re-writing it from scratch and see if the error persists.